# Powershell input box with multiple inputfields

Tags: powershell

I've found this code to create simple input box for powershell:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$title = 'Demographics'
$msg   = 'Enter your demographics:'

$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title)
```

Does anyone know how to add more input fields?

Comment: I'd says use Windows Forms or WPF to make a *real* window with what you need in it, but *maybe* that's overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF, XAML, .NET, and ShowUI are all options available to you.

https://learn-powershell.net/2012/09/13/powershell-and-wpf-introduction-and-building-your-first-window/

http://www.show-ui.com/

also, you can use visual studio community edition (free)
or a paid tool such as https://poshgui.com/

alternatively, here is an example using the `Show-Command` cmdlet

```
function askforinfo {
    param (
        [string]$Demographics,
        [validateset(1, 2, 3)]
        [string]$otherstuff
    )
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Demographics = $Demographics
        OtherStuff = $otherstuff
    }
}

$result = Invoke-Expression (Show-Command askforinfo -PassThru)

$result
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code that's exactly what i need, but i don't know how can i use individual input values as variables, i tried:
`$input1 = $result | Where-Object KeyName -eq 'Demographics' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value`
 
 And then
 
`$input1`

But it doesn't return anything

Comment: try this `$input1 = $result.Demographics`

Comment: Wow! This is awesome :) What a "cheat".